# How to separate variables and arrays out of an expression with StringTokenizer?

Tags: java

I'm trying to separate the arrays and variables from an expression so that I can populate two `ArrayLists` with either array names or variables. I am using `StringTokenizer`. I have the expression broken down, but I am having trouble determining which tokens are array names and which are variables.

```
public void buildSymbols() {
    String s = expr; // input from different part of the program 
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, "+-*/[]() ");
    while(st.hasMoreElements()){
        String temp = st.nextToken();
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
}
```

I print temp just to make sure that the expression is being separated, but given an expression such as  `(varx + vary * varz[(vara + varb[(a + b) * 33])]) / 55` I don't know how to tell that `varz` and `varb` are array names, while varx, vary, vara, a, and `b` are variables.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: You have a way, they are all superseded by the `[` character; you can (easily) check for left bracket element (`[`) and whatever is before it, it's an array...until it ends/closes with `]` (pay attention to arrays inside arrays)

Comment: This is my first time using StringTokenizer, is there a way to check which delimiter is separating the tokens so that I can determine which token is before the `[`?

Comment: You can't get there from here. `StringTokenizer` is the wrong tool for this problem. You need to write yourself a proper lexical analyzer. You have to deal with multi-character identifiers, multi-digit numeric literals, and special characters of several kinds and possibly different lengths. Expressions don't necessarily contain any delimiters (e.g. spaces) at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree wih EJP: The correct solution would be a specific parser. But if you would be content to recognize which delimitter was found by each call to `StringTokenizer.nextToken`, you can tell StringTokenizer to return also the delimitters. Also, you'll need to retrieve the *next* delimitter on every current token (as a *lookahead*). To do that, it's better to store all the tokens in a list:

```
public void buildSymbols() {
    String s = expr; // input from different part of the program 
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, "+-*/[]() ", true);
    Set<String> delimiters=new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"+","-","*","/","[","]","(",")"," "}));
    List<Object> tokens=Collections.list(st);
    for(int i=0;i<tokens.size();i++){
        String temp = tokens.get(i).toString();
        if (delimiters.contains(temp))
        {
            // It is a delimiter
        }
        else
        {
            // It is a term
            boolean isAnArray=(isNextTokenAnOpenBracket(tokens, i));
            ...
        }
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
}

private boolean isNextTokenAnOpenBracket(List<Object> tokens, int currentIndex)
{
    return (currentIndex < tokens.size() && "[".equals(tokens.get(1 + currentIndex)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the String .split() method. It is an alternative to string tokenizer.  You can split a string into an array of smaller strings split by a delimiter, just like StringTokenizer.  However, you could do it two separate times, the first being with brackets, and the second with the other symbols.  Then you know that the last index of your String arrays are the names of Arrays!

```
String s = expr;
String[] brackSplit = s.split("\\[");
for (String str : brackSplit) {
    String[] finalSplit = str.split("*+-/()");
    //finalSplit[finalSplit.length - 1] = Array Name!
}
```

NOTE: StringTokenizer is becoming deprecated with the new version of Java.  The string split() method has become the new "recommended" way of splitting strings by delimiters.

Comment: `String[] brackSplit = s.split("[")` is giving me a `PatternSyntaxException` for an `"Unclosed character class near index 0"`

Comment: I'm sorry.  I changed it to "\\[".  You need the escape character in order for it to be interpreted properly.